# Codewars compiler bug? All tests passed, exit code = 1

Tags: javascript

On Codewars, when I send code for tests, it displays the following message.
All tests passed, but it still exit code 1. What happened? My code incorrect, or it's some bug?

*Screenshot:*

[image: screenshot]

```
function scramble(str1, str2) {
  for (let i = 0; i < str2.length; i++) {
    if (!(str1.indexOf(str2[i])+1)) return false;
    else str1 = str1.replace(str2[i], '');
  }
  return true;
}
```

[link for kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55c04b4cc56a697bb0000048/train/javascript)

// sorry for my bad english

Comment: It's a time limit problem, your code is correct but too slow

Comment: @ChatterOne, but why is this happend? all tests already gone, everything okay, what i have to change?

Comment: You need to figure out a faster algorithm - that's part of the point

Comment: As said by the *Why did my code time out?* section, it could be the server as well.

Comment: @ChristhoferNatalius, all in all, changing my algorithm from indexOf usage to object properties has resolved time problem.

Comment: Happened with me a lot of times. Yes your code produces correct output. But thats not what the kata wants. The kata wants you to think of a faster algorithm